# Strange behavior of 555 timer

Tags: 555, troubleshooting

Having problems with the 555 timer, I have decided to configure it in the simplest way possible to test its behavior, by controlling only the inputs to the `trigger` and `threshold` pins.
I tied the `threshold` pin `HIGH` through a push-button, and `LOW` through a pull-down resistor. I did the opposite (pushing the button ties `LOW`) for the `trigger`.
In this configuration pressing the switches `set` and `reset` results in the same action on the `SR latch`.

**Results:**
I have found that once the output goes `LOW`, I can't toggle it back to `HIGH`. pressing `reset` switches off the LED as expected.

| Process | Result |
| --- | --- |
| close `set` -> connect battery | LED lights up (expected) |
| connect battery -> close `set` | LED is off |

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feX5Wc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note: Voltage and resistance shown in the schematic is exactly what I have used.

Why can't I set the `SR latch` once the output goes off. Is the 555 timer supposed behave like this? If so why. Or is my 555 timer broken?

Comment: Tie the reset pin (pin 4) high.

Comment: I have done that. Let me update the diagram.

Comment: You should have a current limiting resistor on your LED

Comment: I do have a current limiting resistor (400 ohm) and tried various values of resistances for R1 and R2. I noticed that there was a random chance of the LED not lighting up (even in the aforementioned scenario) at high resistances of 5K - 10K. Perhaps that helps.

Comment: If you keep treshold input low, even trigger is high, output stills low. Release threshold.

Comment: Hmm the diagram I found for a [555 SR Latch](https://www.dummies.com/programming/electronics/components/electronics-components-the-555-in-bistable-flip-flop-mode/) also requires two resistors.  The configuration is different from yours, but you might want to try it because it functions more intuitively.  Pull Pin 2(TRIGGER) low to set, pull Pin 4(~RESET) low to reset.  Messing with threshold is less direct.  That said I don't see why your layout wouldn't work.  Instead of using a pulldown resistor on THRESH you could try a voltage divider to hold it between 1/3 and 2/3 VCC.

Comment: Before trying that you could pop in a known working 555 and see if that makes the circuit work.  I also personally would just set up a slow blinking LED with an astable multivibrator to test a 555.  Full function test and super easy set up.  Do you only have one 555?